# PHP json_decode brings back null

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I am trying to get this to work but can't see where I'm going wrong. Can anyone assist?

```
<?php
    $jsonurl        =   'http://www.foxsports.com.au/internal-syndication/json/livescoreboard';
    $json           =   file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
    $json_output    =   var_dump(json_decode($json,true)); 

    echo $json_output
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

The initial JSON (stored in `$json` variable) does NOT validate.

**Code :** (FIXED)

```
<?php

$jsonurl='http://www.foxsports.com.au/internal-syndication/json/livescoreboard';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);

$json = strip_tags(str_replace("jQuery.fs['scoreboard'].data =","",$json));

$json_output = var_dump(json_decode($json,true)); 

echo $json_output;

?>
```

This will work. :-)

Comment: Sorry Its not working for me I get "NULL - Syntax error, malformed JSON". Does it have something to do with the json being in quotation marks?

Comment: @Gopher It was working. In the meantime, the JSON suddenly contains... comments which cause it to crash. Give me a minute, and I'll see what we can do...

Comment: @Gopher We're now stripping comments out (`strip_tags`), and it's working (again); I've checked that myself just right now... :-)

Comment: Thankyou Dr.Kameleon for your fast response. It now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON source is not valid. You can try this validator http://jsonlint.com/