# JSON DECODE Assoc Array

Tags: php, json

I have been working on a json decode issue (which I have already had assistance with thanks very much - [PHP json_decode brings back null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849562/php-json-decode-brings-back-null) ).
but I find I have another problem getting the assoc array brought back by the json decode to work properly. Am I doing something wrong or is it the array?? Here is my code

```
<?php
$jsonurl='http://www.foxsports.com.au/internal-syndication/json/livescoreboard';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);

$json = str_replace("jQuery.fs['scoreboard'].data =","",$json); /*
replace starting comment*/

$json =strip_tags($json); /* takes out html tags  & comments*/


$json_output = json_decode($json,true); 

switch(json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
      //  echo ' - No errors';
    break; }


function crttbl($test){ echo "</br></br>";

echo "<table border='1'>";
    foreach($test as $key=>$row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $key2=>$row2){
            echo "<td>". $key2.": " .$row2 . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    } echo "</table>";

echo "</br></br>"; }



//print_r (array_keys($json_output)); $test=$json_output["response"];
print_r(array_keys($test)); crttbl($test);

echo var_dump($test);

$test=$test['container-1']; print_r(array_keys($test)); crttbl($test);

echo var_dump($test);

$test=$test['group-content-1']; print_r(array_keys($test));
crttbl($test);
```

Comment: And what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. As the copy says: “this question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors”. In future, include at very least a description of the problem you're having, and make some attempt to post only the minimum amount of code required to recreate it.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to state what the actual _problem_ is `:(`

Comment: Quick tip: StackOverflow and sites like it are not replacements for doing your own debugging. Questions here need to demonstrate a thorough go at fixing the problem - it helps encourage beginners to become better programmers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the output you are after
http://cl.ly/0t2a2y3r2k2Q0B2x1o2h

Then try this:

```
function createTable(&$node, &$output, $key = NULL, $indent = 0) {
    if ($indent > 0) {
        $output .= "<tr>\n";
        $output .= "<td><strong>". $key."</strong></td>";
    } else {
        $output .= '<tr><td>Top Level</td>';
    }
    if (is_object($node) || is_array($node)) {
        $node = (array)$node;
        $output .= "</tr>\n";
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($node as $k=>$v) {
            createTable($node[$k], $output, $k, $indent + 1);
        }
    } else {
        $output .= "<td>".($node === TRUE ? 1 : $node === FALSE ? 0 : $node) ."</td>";
        $output .= "</tr>\n";
    }
}

function outputTable($object) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
            $output = "";
            createTable($object, $output); 
            echo $output; 
    echo "</table>";
}

outputTable($json_output);
```

The problem with your original code is that your object is nested more than two levels, so when you do `foreach($row as $key2=>$row2) {`, $row2 is actually an Array and you simply get the word `Array` in your output.

Since you can't be 100% sure (at least I don't think you can) of the number of levels deep the response might be, you are best off using a recursive-ish function like I provided.

Comment: sberry - thanks for the response. Thats what i needed to know. This is my first attempt at decoding json. The issues around recursion are new to me.